# How does Postgresql's '%' affect a LIKE comparison

Tags: string, postgresql, wildcard

When comparing the results of a function which returns TEXT, `LIKE '%word'`, or `LIKE 'word%'` will produce a match, but not `LIKE 'word'`.

```
SELECT extract_json_text(lst_logs.data) AS machine
   FROM lst_logs WHERE extract_json_text(lst_logs.data) LIKE 'Cupra';
```

Gives me no results, but

```
SELECT extract_json_text(lst_logs.data) AS machine
       FROM lst_logs WHERE extract_json_text(lst_logs.data) LIKE '%Cupra';
```

or even

```
SELECT extract_json_text(lst_logs.data) AS machine
       FROM lst_logs WHERE extract_json_text(lst_logs.data) LIKE 'Cupra%';
```

Gives me what I want, yet my results say that the text is `Cupra`.

How is `%` able to effect the match from either side of the string?

EDIT Here is the function which extracts the text.  There are escaped quotes inside the JSON which is which I use TRIM.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cupra.lst_machine(jsonb)
  RETURNS text
IMMUTABLE
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN (TRIM(BOTH '\"' FROM $1->>5));
END;
$$;
```

Comment: `extract_json_text` is not a standard postgres function afaik - can you share the code for that?

Comment: Maybe you have hidden characters. do `= 'Cupra'` return results?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza = does not return results either

Comment: Then your string isn't really `'Cupra'` maybe you have special characters that is why the % is able to find it.

Comment: I figured that, but how is `%` matching at both the beginning and end of the word?  And is there any way I can detect the special characters?

Comment: `SELECT (extract_json_text(lst_logs.data))::bytea::text AS machine, 'Cupra'::bytea::text ...` - will return hex representation of the strings, char by char, so you'll be able to compare it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of how [LIKE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) works.

The `%` is a wildcard match.

Stating `LIKE 'word'` is the equivalent to stating `= 'word'`; that is to state, "look for 'word' and exactly 'word' as the entire contents of the field." However, `LIKE` is slower than `=` in that instance.

Adding `%` to the mix causes `LIKE` to find 'word' anywhere in the string. It doesn't care which side the `%` is placed.

To find out what's in front, you can get the code point by doing:

```
SELECT ascii(extract_json_text(lst_logs.data)) AS first_char_code_point
  FROM lst_logs WHERE extract_json_text(lst_logs.data) LIKE 'Cupra%' LIMIT 1;
```

`ascii()` will only return the code point for the first character. If it isn't *67*, then you've found your culprit.

For the last character, the following should do the trick:

```
SELECT ascii(substr(extract_json_text(lst_logs.data),
       length(extract_json_text(lst_logs.data))) AS last_char_code_point
  FROM lst_logs WHERE extract_json_text(lst_logs.data) LIKE 'Cupra%' LIMIT 1;
```

If it isn't *97*, then you've found your culprit.